# How to make a variable value once read by a thread does't change by other thread when other process started in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot rest controller from there it is calling service to get data and the return type is `List` in service class. It is Async rest controller. My Issue is for the first hit I'm getting the list with expected data and the remaining process is continuing the program still not comes to end at this point, in the middle of the code I'm again using that list. But what happens is for the 2nd and 3rd hit, the list from service is empty, which is expected for my case but it is setting empty even for the first thread I'm getting the empty value in the middle where I'm using the list again.

```
@RestController
public class ControllerClass1 
{

    @Autowired
    Serviceclass serviceclass;
    
    @GetMapping("/v1")
    public List<String> m1()
    {
         List<String> m1 = serviceclass.m1();//for the 2nd thread this list is empty ..even for the first thread the value is setting empty in middle of first process which is not expected 
         //First time expected data
         //Assue its a huge code i'm using this list again in middle
         return m1();//dummy return
    }
    
}
```

we are calling service as `Completeablefuture.runasync(serviceclass.m1())` to make sure it runs asynchronously

---

```
@Service
public class Serviceclass {
    
    public List<String> m1()
    {
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("test1");
        a.add("test2");
        a.add("test3");
        return a;
    }
}
```

Note: The code is not the actual one I'm just making sure you understand my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your issue, following is one possible solution.

In your service, returning `CompletableFuture` instead:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> m1() {
  List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
  a.add("test1");
  a.add("test2");
  a.add("test3");
  return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(a);
}
```

Using `CompletableFuture.join()` in your controller:

```
@GetMapping("/v1")
public List<String> m1() {
  CompletableFuture<List<String>> c1 = serviceclass.m1();
  
  // ... your logic ...

  return c1.join();
}
```